# Automatically reload rails yml files in config/locales

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In rails, the yml files in config/locales allow you to give locale-specific text and formatting directives. For example, you can specify date formatting like this:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
  date: 
    formats:
      month: "%B, %Y"
```

Then in your views you can use the helper, like this:

```
<%= l(Date.today, format: :month) %> => "December, 2013"
```

Annoyingly, rails only loads the locale files when you start your server, so you have to restart your development server if you want to make a change. Is it possible to automatically reload this on file changes?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think Rails misses new translation files, but adding translations to an existing file should work.

Try force reload it with `I18n.backend.reload!`

I hope this helps ;)

Comment: Very helpful! I added an answer with the actual code I'm using, since I wanted to reload it only when files changed.

Comment: Where does one type this?

Answer (score 9):

There's attempted support for this in rails 3.2:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.16/activesupport/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb

However, it comes with this disclaimer:

```
# Add <tt>I18n::Railtie.reloader</tt> to ActionDispatch callbacks. Since, at this
# point, no path was added to the reloader, I18n.reload! is not triggered
# on to_prepare callbacks. This will only happen on the config.after_initialize
# callback below.
```

There's some better looking code in rails 4, so this problem might be fixed there (I don't use rails 4 yet).

I added the following initializer, which checks for changed files is config/locales and reloads I18n:

```
# config/initializers/reload_locale.rb
if Rails.env == 'development'
  locale_reloader = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker.new(Dir["config/locales/*yml"]) do
     I18n.backend.reload!
  end

  ActionDispatch::Callbacks.to_prepare do
    locale_reloader.execute_if_updated
  end
end
```

Comment: Awesome! tks for sharing!

Comment: Ehm, why add an initializer? You have to restart your server to run it, and restarting would reload i18n anyways.. What I want is to auto-reload it while the app is running, when any changes occur in that directory.

Comment: @Magne The initializer is setting up a file watcher for all files in "config/locales/*yml". Whenever any of those files changes,      I18n.backend.reload! is called.

Comment: @spike have you an other trick to autoreload `/config/initialized/*.rb` file? I have some custum modules. It's borring to reload server for each modiication... thx.

Comment: @Matrix not sure without seeing exactly what you're reloading. You'll get a better reply if you ask a standalone question

Comment: FYI for Rails 5 this is now `ActionDispatch::Callbacks.before`

Answer (score 2):

I18n detects changes made to **existing** files in its load path, but if you want to detect new files under `locales` and add them to the load path at runtime, try this.

```
# config/initializers/i18n_load_path.rb
if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
  locales_path = Rails.root.join("config/locales").to_s
  i18n_reloader = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker.new([], locales_path => "yml") do
    Dir["#{locales_path}/*.yml"].each do |locale_path|
      I18n.load_path << locale_path unless I18n.load_path.include? locale_path
    end
  end

  ActiveSupport::Reloader.to_prepare do
    i18n_reloader.execute_if_updated
  end
end
```

That will monitor the locales directory (or any other directory you want to store locales) and add missing ones to the load path when they are added. I18n picks up on these added files so no need to call `reload!`.

Comment: Can't believe my question from 2013 just got an answer from the man behind railscasts! Thanks so much for those, they really helped me out back in the day.